# Circular Pane in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I've been working on a project that needs a Pane displaying nodes in a circle using JavaFX.

This is a university's work so I must not use extern libraries as JFxtras.

Doing a little research I found this class in stackoverflow.

```
public class CircularPane extends Pane {
    private long degreese = 0;
    private long increment;
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        final int radius = 250;
        final double increment = 360 / getChildren().size();
        double degreese = 0;
        for (Node node : getChildren()) {
            double x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degreese)) + getWidth() / 2;
            double y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degreese)) + getHeight() / 2;
            layoutInArea(node, x - node.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0.0, HPos.LEFT, VPos.TOP);
            degreese += increment;
        }
    }  
}
```

At the beginning I thought it work fine, but later I noticed this.
When I add 40 nodes to the pane it shows this:
[image]

But when I try to display 41 nodes, this is what happened:

[image]

I didn't really know what was happening until I figured out that white space only appears when I try to show n nodes in the pane and 360 in not divisible by n.
Does anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

Beforehand, thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

You're dividing two `int`s to calculate the angle. This will truncate the result to an integral value. Assuming you want to place `n` nodes the result could be wrong by a value less than `n-1` (the error is smaller than 1 for each "step").

Just make sure to use a floating point division instead. This way the results should be much more accurate:

```
final double increment = 360d / getChildren().size();
//                          ^ modification here
```

Since the first dividend is a `double` the `int` returned by `size()` is automatically promoted to `double` and the floating point division happens. If you don't add the `d` suffix, both operands are `int`s resulting in the problematic division described above.

Comment: So that was my mistake, I tried it and now it works fine. Thank you very much!